# Fetch From a Dump Array

Tags: codeigniter

I have a dump array and want the value of `email`, how can I do it?

```
string(614) "a:6:{s:10:"session_id";s:32:"f0fd7825ad5e0760c635f136e1f508db";s:10:"ip_address";s:15:"202.142.176.142";s:10:"user_agent";s:120:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36 OPR/27.0.1";s:13:"last_activity";i:1423743791;s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:9:"logged_in";a:8:{s:7:"user_id";s:2:"78";s:8:"username";s:5:"Ahsan";s:7:"role_id";s:1:"1";s:9:"user_type";s:8:"Reseller";s:19:"reseller_company_id";s:1:"1";s:9:"full_name";s:14:"Muhammad Ahsan";s:5:"email";s:17:"ahsan@tasmimy.com";s:5:"thumb";s:18:"14236608537282.jpg";}}e92d7c14027cd35d0a2e45e3e0d50328"
```

Comment: Where does it come from ? Is it your session ? Why a dump ?

Comment: yes, but i don,t know how to fetch email ? plz help

Comment: Show us the function where you try to do this please. I think a simple session->userdata() should do the trick but I can't be sure without more details

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to get the session is after you have set your sessions.

Auto load session library and add encryption key in config.php and enable sessions. **Codeigniter 2.2.1** and **Codeigniter 3** are different slightly.

```
$data = array(
'isLogged' => true,
'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

Then you should be able to use echo `$this->session->userdata('email');`